# site doesn't work in Chrome14

Tags: google-chrome, https

Our site: http://shiftd.com is broken in Chrome 14. But it works fine under Safari and Firefox. Does anyone know why?

"Inspect Element" just shows an error on the GET request (failed). But with no additional information at all.

I don't even know how to debug it... :/

Mosko

Comment: fyi, doesn't seem to open in IE 9 either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The HTTP url issues a `301 Moved Permanently` to the HTTPS url that then serves up a corrupt gzipped document, check your server settings.

(Fiddler; `HTTP Error: The chunked entity body is corrupt. Cannot find Chunk-Length in expected location. Offset: 1405`)

Chrome Error; `Error 321 (net::ERR_INVALID_CHUNKED_ENCODING): Unknown error.`

It works ok if I disable gzip,deflate in my browser.

Comment: What causes this? We're running Cherokee 1.299. It just started happening about 20 minutes ago. Have been using it for months without issue.

Comment: Known bug? *File download with gzip compression enabled on SSL connection fails* http://code.google.com/p/cherokee/issues/detail?id=1243 - In the interim disable gzip & post on the cherokee forum?

Comment: Thanks Alex. That solved our problem for now... Pretty shocking that that type of bug exists in a webserver.

Answer (score 0):

right click -> choose "Inspect Element" to debug

Comment: Sorry my first post didn't make it clear. But I definitely did all of those standard things first. There are no error messages that are helpful in the console. Just an error on the main GET request. With no more information.